# Extrapolation of dataset based on index

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate my dataset. A snippet looks as follows. A simple linear extrapolation is fine here:

```
Index Value
3000  NaN
4000  NaN
5000  10
6000  20
6500  33
7000  44  
8300  60
9300  NaN
9400  NaN
```

The extrapolation should consider the index values. As the pandas package only provides a function for interpolation, I am stuck. I looked at scipy package, but cant seem to implement my idea. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with scikit-learn:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(3000,  np.nan),
(4000,  np.nan),
(5000,  10),
(6000,  20),
(6500,  33),
(7000,  44  ),
(8300,  60),
(9300,  np.nan),
(9400,  np.nan)], columns=['Index', 'Value'])
```

```py
def extrapolate(df, X_col, y_col):
    
    df_ = df[[X_col, y_col]].dropna()
    
    return LinearRegression().fit(
        df_[X_col].values.reshape(-1,1), df_[y_col]).predict(
        df[X_col].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

```py
df['Value_'] = extrapolate(df, 'Index', 'Value')
df
```

You should obtain something like this:

```
    Index   Value   Value_
0   3000    NaN     -23.219022
1   4000    NaN     -7.314802
2   5000    10.0    8.589417
3   6000    20.0    24.493637
4   6500    33.0    32.445747
5   7000    44.0    40.397857
6   8300    60.0    61.073342
7   9300    NaN     76.977562
8   9400    NaN     78.567984
```

```py
# I assume you don't want to extrapolate the orginal values
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df['Value_'])
df
```

Gives:

```
    Index   Value   Value_
0   3000    -23.219022  -23.219022
1   4000    -7.314802   -7.314802
2   5000    10.000000   8.589417
3   6000    20.000000   24.493637
4   6500    33.000000   32.445747
5   7000    44.000000   40.397857
6   8300    60.000000   61.073342
7   9300    76.977562   76.977562
8   9400    78.567984   78.567984
```